# python square bracket usage

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I saw a code fragment similar to below while learning python. I am new to both python and pandas and want to understand how is the usage of square brackets, with a text in it, allowed for the DataFrame instance? I thought square bracket is used for lists and to retrieve elements based on index. What is in the DataFrame implementation that instruct interpreter to allow this usage of square bracket?

```
fram = pandas.read_csv(csvpath)
fame["city"].value_counts()
```

Comment: check the `__getitem__` method on any class :) Here [How to access element like ](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__ )

Comment: This is extremely basic Python usage. I suggest working through the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python docs for [`__getitem__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) explain this

> Called to implement evaluation of `self[key]`.

Pandas has some neat syntactic implementations to make it so you can slice a Dataframe's row with an index (e.g. `df[42]`), a Dataframe's column with a column name (e.g. `df['spam']`) and [other methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html).